Как реализовать запрет записи строк в числовое значение
Настраиваю таблицу:

В коде из csv фала в таблицу переносится множество значений, неизвестно есть ли в csv файле первая строка, как названия колонок. Вот эту самую строку python смог инсертнуть в таблицу, хотя в колонке semester явно тип данных INTEGER.
Могу ли я ограничить ввод данных?
Данное действие не проходит в исключение.
try:
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO {table} VALUES ({values})', row)
    connection.commit()
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    pass


Как насчёт добавить ограничение check на колонку? Что-то вроде: create table subjects (semester integer check (semester>0 and semester<10). Значения укажите нужные.

А ещё, проверку первой строки файла можно сделать в питоне.

Добавил проверку в бд, сработало. Непонятно, почему вообще в int можно записать text

В sqlite нет строгой типизации. Срабатывает affinity. См. документацию: Datatypes In SQLite.

Кстати, есть ещё один способ: задать таблице опцию STRICT.
